# How to split a multiple string using t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tried to split this string but unsuccessful because of the way the string is arranged in the column. The Null value keeps appearing on the Make and model column and the actually data goes to the wrong column

Sample data:

| MakeModelColor |
| --- |
| Apple - iphone 12 |
| Apple - iphone 12 pro max - black -128gb |
| Samsung - galaxy A12 |

This is the result I am looking for:

| Make | Model |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | iphone 12 |
| Apple | iphone 12 pro max |
| Samsung | Galaxy A12 |

[Actual result am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vsMS.png) ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvzYN.png)

Comment: Provide sample data and desired output as TEXT.

Comment: For some tips on how you could improve your question see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
and how not to use [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, code or errors

Comment: You need to add your attempt to the question also.

Comment: Aside: It's best not to try to bend `ParseName` into doing other things. Give it a string longer than a `sysname` or a string with more than three dots and it fails _hard_. Try munging other separators into dots and something else will break, e.g. `'Bedlam - GerbilFone v.2 - paisley'` has a dot in the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just another option using a bit of JSON

**Example**

```
 Select Make  = trim(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]'))
       ,Model = trim(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]'))
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape([MakeModelColor],'json'),'-','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

```
Make            Model
Apple           iphone 12
Apple           iphone 12 pro max
Samsung galaxy  A12
```

Answer (score 2):

That could be done in a number of ways. ie:

```
with data(makeModelColor, part, ordinal) as (
  select makeModelColor, ltrim(rtrim(value)), ordinal
from devices
cross apply (select * from String_Split(devices.makeModelColor,'-',1)) t)
select makeModelColor,
  max(case when ordinal = 1 then part end) as Make,
  max(case when ordinal = 2 then part end) as Model,
  max(case when ordinal = 3 then part end) as Color,
  max(case when ordinal = 4 then part end) as Other
  from data
group by makeModelColor;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9oTIo9ZJ)

Comment: Thanks for your input but but my t-sql does not recognise string_split command because of the version but issue is resolved with @john cappelleti solution

Comment: @TimothyObidike, then you should mark that as answer. I wonder which version is that having JSON_VALUE but not STRING_SPLIT. AFAIK both are available since SQL Server 2016 (13.x) - ordinal parameter was not supported initially.